# Validation message should be gone while i click on that field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model

I have a doubt regarding validation messages in mvc4. my validation works perfectly but when i keep both username and password fields empty , it give me the validation message that "you can't leave this empty" , so it is okey but when I click on that field and enter the username or password that message should be gone but it's not happen , it goes when i click on login button... so can anyone help?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            if (model.UserName == null && model.Password == null)
            {
                return View();

            }
            else
            {
                var errors = ModelState
                   .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                   .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
                   .ToArray();
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid && model.UserName != null && model.Password != null && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
                    {
                        UsersContext usercontext = new UsersContext();
                        var profile = usercontext.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(d => d.UserName.Equals(model.UserName));
                        if (profile != null)
                        {
                            Session["LogedUserFirstName"] = profile.FirstName;
                            Session["Email"] = profile.Email;
                            Session["Username"] = profile.UserName;
                            Session["LastName"] = profile.LastName;
                            Session["MobileNumber"] = profile.MobileNumber;
                            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Admin"))
                            {
                                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Base");
                            }
                            else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "User"))
                            {
                                return RedirectToAction("myProfile");

                            }
                            else {


                            }

                        }
                        else if (model.UserName == null && model.Password == null) { }
                        else if (model.UserName == null && model.Password != null) { }
                        else if (model.UserName != null && model.Password == null) { }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewBag.Message("Username does not exist...");
                            return View(model);
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    ViewBag.Message = "Username or Password provided is incorrect...";
                    return View();
                }

            }

        }
        catch
        {

            ViewBag.Message("OOPs.... Something went wrong");
            return View();
        }


        return View(model);
    }
```

View

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
                                {
                                    if (ViewBag.Message != null)
                                    { 
                                            <h6  style="color:#ff0000;width:350px;">@ViewBag.Message</h6>
                                    }
                                }

                                @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
                                {
                                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                                    <fieldset id="login_form">
                                        <label class="block clearfix" style="text-align: left">
                                            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "UserName" })
                                                <p id="log_valid">
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)</p>
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="block clearfix" style="text-align: left">
                                            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
                                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" })
                                                <p id="log_valid">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)</p>
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="space" style="text-align: left">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix">
                                            <label class="inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox"  class="ace" checked= "@ViewBag.IsCheck" name="agreecheckbox" value="check" />
                                                <span class="lbl">Remember Me</span> <span>@ViewBag.Msg</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <button type="submit" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("AfterLogin", "Account"));" >
                                                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-key"></i><span class="bigger-110">Login</span>
                                            </button>
                                            <a href="@Url.Action("forgotPassword", "Account")">
                                                <h6>
                                                    Forgot Password?</h6>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                }
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.widget-main -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.widget-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.login-box -->
                    <div id="forgot-box" class="forgot-box widget-box no-border">
                        <div class="widget-body">
                            <div class="widget-main">
                                <h4 class="header red lighter bigger">
                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-key"></i>Retrieve Password
                                </h4>
                                <div class="space-6">
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    Enter your Username
                                </p>
                                <form>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <label class="block clearfix">
                                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                            <input type="UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                        <button type="button" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("forgotPassword", "Account")'">
                                            Send Me <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                                </form>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: Why are you adding your 'error message' to `ViewBag`? The correct approach is to add it to `ModelState` - `ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password provided is incorrect...");` and then return the view (and the message with be displayed in the `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` placeholder.

Comment: But i want to style my element that's why i had used viewbag.message

Comment: Then style the placeholder generated by `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`. But there are numerous other issues with your code in the POST method. You first check `if(!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(model); }` not `if (model.UserName == null && model.Password == null){ ...`. And delete all your `else if` statements. And what is the point of `var errors = ModelState.Where(....`?